# Right to Left print preview

Tags: vb.net, listview

i hope you all good, i already working on printing list view items and some labels, every thing work perfect, but the list view and labels print from left to right, and the items in the lest view in Arabic, so how can i make it from right to left ?

this is my code:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim PrintPreview As New PrintPreviewDialog
    PrintPreview.Document = PrintDocument1
    PrintPreview.ShowDialog()
End Sub
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    'Keep track of the Line Y postition to determine if there are more pages
    Static CurrentYPosition As Integer = 0
    'The below is desined for details view.
    If ListView1.View = View.Details Then
        PrintDetails(e)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub PrintDetails(ByRef e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
    Static LastIndex As Integer = 0
    Static CurrentPage As Integer = 0
    'Getting the current dpi so the textleftpad 
    'will be the same on a different dpi than 
    'the 96 i'm using.  Won't make much of a difference though.
    Dim DpiGraphics As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
    Dim DpiX As Integer = DpiGraphics.DpiX
    Dim DpiY As Integer = DpiGraphics.DpiY
    DpiGraphics.Dispose()
    Dim X, Y As Integer
    Dim ImageWidth As Integer
    Dim TextRect As Rectangle = Rectangle.Empty
    Dim TextLeftPad As Single = CSng(-4 * (DpiX / 96)) '4 pixel pad on the left.
    Dim ColumnHeaderHeight As Single = CSng(ListView1.Font.Height + (10 * (DpiX / 96))) '5 pixel pad on the top an bottom
    Dim StringFormat As New StringFormat
    Dim PageNumberWidth As Single = e.Graphics.MeasureString(CStr(CurrentPage), ListView1.Font).Width
    'Specify the text should be drawn in the center of the line and
    'that the text should not be wrapped and the text should show
    'ellipsis would cut off.

    StringFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoWrap
    StringFormat.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
    StringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    CurrentPage += 1
    'Start the x and  y at the top left margin.
    X = CInt(e.MarginBounds.X)
    Y = CInt(e.MarginBounds.Y)
    'Draw the column headers
    For ColumnIndex As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Columns.Count - 1
        TextRect.X = X
        TextRect.Y = Y
        TextRect.Width = ListView1.Columns(ColumnIndex).Width
        TextRect.Height = ColumnHeaderHeight
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, TextRect)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkGray, TextRect)
        'TextLeftPad adds a little padding from the gridline.
        'Add it to the left and subtract it from the right.
        TextRect.X += TextLeftPad
        TextRect.Width -= TextLeftPad
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListView1.Columns(ColumnIndex).Text, ListView1.Font, Brushes.Black, TextRect, StringFormat)
        'Move the x position over the width of the column width.
        'Since I subtracted some padding add the padding back
        'when offsetting.
        X += TextRect.Width + TextLeftPad
    Next
    'Just drew the headers.  Move the Y down the height
    'of the column headers.
    Y += ColumnHeaderHeight
    'Now draw the items.  If this is the first page then the 
    'last index will be zero.  If its not then the last index
    'will be the last index we tried to draw but had no room.
    For i = LastIndex To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        With ListView1.Items(i)
            'Start the x at the pages left margin.
            X = CInt(e.MarginBounds.X)
            'Check for Last Line
            If Y + .Bounds.Height > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                'This item won't fit.
                'subtract 1 from i so the next time this sub
                'is entered we can start with this item.
                LastIndex = i - 1
                e.HasMorePages = True
                StringFormat.Dispose()
                'Draw the current page number before leaving.
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Label1.Text, Label1.Font, Brushes.Blue, 100, 20)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Label4.Text, Label4.Font, Brushes.Blue, 150, 20)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Label2.Text, Label2.Font, Brushes.Blue, 350, 20)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Label3.Text, Label3.Font, Brushes.Blue, 600, 20)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(CStr(CurrentPage), ListView1.Font, Brushes.Black, (e.PageBounds.Width - PageNumberWidth) / 2, e.PageBounds.Bottom - ListView1.Font.Height * 2)
                Exit Sub
            End If
            'Print Images.
            'The image width is used so we can draw the gridline
            'around the image about to be drawn.  You'll see it 
            'below.
            ImageWidth = 0
            If ListView1.SmallImageList IsNot Nothing Then
                'If the image key is set then draw the image
                'with the key .  If not draw the image with the
                'index.  A tiny bit of validation would be good.
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(.ImageKey) Then
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(ListView1.SmallImageList.Images(.ImageKey), X, Y)
                ElseIf .ImageIndex >= 0 Then
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(ListView1.SmallImageList.Images(.ImageIndex), X, Y)
                End If
                ImageWidth = ListView1.SmallImageList.ImageSize.Width
            End If
            'Now draw the subitems.  using the columns count so the 
            'grid lines can be drawn.  If used the subitems count then
            'the table would not be full if some subitems where less
            'than others.
            For ColumnIndex As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Columns.Count - 1
                TextRect.X = X
                TextRect.Y = Y
                TextRect.Width = ListView1.Columns(ColumnIndex).Width
                TextRect.Height = .Bounds.Height
                If ListView1.GridLines Then
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkGray, TextRect)
                End If
                'If an image is drawn then shift over the x to 
                'accomadate its width. If this was shifted before
                'now then the gridline with draw rect above would be
                ' on the wrong side of the image.
                If ColumnIndex = 0 Then TextRect.X += ImageWidth
                'Add a little padding from the gridline.
                TextRect.X += TextLeftPad
                TextRect.Width -= TextLeftPad
                If ColumnIndex < .SubItems.Count Then
                    'This item has at least the same number of
                    'subitems as the current column index.
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(.SubItems(ColumnIndex).Text, ListView1.Font, Brushes.Black, TextRect, StringFormat)
                End If
                'Shift the x of the width of this subitem.
                'Add some padding to the left side of the text
                'so need to add it back.
                X += TextRect.Width + TextLeftPad
            Next
            'Set the next line
            Y += .Bounds.Height
        End With
    Next

    'Draw the final page number.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(CStr(CurrentPage), ListView1.Font, Brushes.Black, (e.PageBounds.Width - PageNumberWidth) / 2, e.PageBounds.Bottom - ListView1.Font.Height * 2 )

    StringFormat.Dispose()
    LastIndex = 1

    CurrentPage = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you changed the RightToLeft property for the listview in the designer window? And are you setting this property for any controls you create at runtime?

Comment: yes i already did that , the form propriety Right to Left is yes , so everything in the form right to left.